# Should I store user id's and profile data (10-15 columns) separately?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, schema

I am using PHP and MyISAM, currently I have a profile page for users and am unsure of how I should exactly lay out the tables.

I have tables for users (and every bit of their profile including a pair of MEDIUMTEXT fields for their long description or custom stylesheet,) a table for friends (userid+friendid) and of course a table for comments that may have been placed on their page.

Would it be wise to separate the profile/extra user data from the user table and purely use it for checking with the other tables?

I am unsure if many/or some long fields in each of the rows would be inappropriate if I were just checking for their friends to display or something on another page.

Comment: Can you post your table schema, and what exactly you want to separate?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6418154/367456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is maybe. Seperating the tables will save space because if the field is not used space will not be allocated. Space probably wont be a concern ( depending on the server and userbase ) but joining tables can slow performance down but again this depends on the userbase and the server. I think primary keys indexes are stored in memory so lookups shouldnt be affected by the number of columns / size of a row.

speed / performance      ... denormalize

space                        normalize

Comment: this makes more sense to me (and user ids are indeed primary keys) - I have more confidence just going as I should being a simple and small application.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your questions can not be really answered as it's very subjective, so this is more or less some opinion to chime in:

> Would it be wise to separate the profile/extra user data from the user column and purely use it for checking with the other tables?

It seems so, because you call it **extra** user data. So it does not belong to user and should be kept apart of it.

> I am unsure if many/or some long fields in each of the rows would be inappropriate if I were just checking for their friends to display or something on another page.

That's hard to answer as well with the information you provide. If you've only doing `SELECT * FROM TABLE;` queries however, then it would be definitely inappropriate.

Comment: I apologize, I was just wondering if I were going to have a substantial amount of columns if I were just requiring the user ID in the table, if it would be appropriate to have all that data there.

Comment: Do you want to achieve true normalization? What is your goal?

Comment: Normalization would be important to me, however it seems I really need to read more about how I should define the relationships in my application before I go one way or the other here (even if it is correct,) I think I asked an impossible question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to create a separate table for the profile/extra user data. Keep frequently used column in the user table and move other columns in the new user_profile table. Currently you have 10 - 15 columns but in future it may grow to 50+ columns. So it is better to separate now.

HTH,