# Adding a foreign key to a table,from two tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, polymorphism

I have two tables called lawyer & client.And  they are the users of my site .so i have another table  called users to store their username,password.But i have to add a foreign key which references  clientID(from client table),lawyerId(from lawyer table) to User table.
how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds backwards; as lawyers & clients are users, their IDs should be referencing the ID in the users table, not the other way around (not every user is a lawyer and client; in fact, some could presumably be neither.)  Or am I misreading what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple foreign key references for a single primary key column. Here is a simple example of how to re-design your schema to facilitate your requirements.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Users(
    ->    userID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=INNODB;

mysql> CREATE TABLE Client(
    ->    userID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users (userID)
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=INNODB;

mysql> CREATE TABLE Lawyer(
    ->    userID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users (userID)
    -> )
    -> ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Why storing passwords in three places?