# Relationship with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, polymorphic-associations

I have Tables; Category, Subject, and Grade.

```
Category -> id, name, desc; 
Subject -> id, name, desc, category_id; 
Grade -> id, name, desc, subject_id.
```

And I have another table, Price. It is currently

```
Price -> id, amount, category_id.
```

Yes, prices was added to categories, but new requirement is, price can be added to any level, that is Category, Subject, or Grade.

I know a way to solve it by adding rest Foreign Keys to Price table, as -> id, amount, category_id, subject_id, grade_id. Then leave them NULL than related table.

I don't know, it is better solution, and I like to create perfect database schema. Please suggest me alternative better solutions.

I use MySQL and PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Add price numeric field to each table**

I would say one solution is to directly add an amount field to each of your three tables, and dispense with relationships. 
Any object that does not have a price will have a zero price.

**Solution 2: Create three price relationship tables**

You could create three tables these being:

```
CategoryPrice -> Category_ID, Price
SubjectPrice -> Subject_ID, Price
GradePrice -> Grade_ID, Price
```

For rows in your three original tables that don't have a price you omit entry within the price relationship tables.

**Solution 3: Create a supertype type to join with a Prices Table**

You could create a supertype table called "Object" that will have a unique ID.
All categories, subjects, and grades will by subtypes of Object, and hence share the same ID.

Therefore, you can use the Object_ID within the Prices table to assign prices to objects.

Comment: Solution 1 is not applicable, because Prices can be changed with terms. I avoided Term ID in price table.

Comment: Very nice idea -> Solution 3. Thanks.