# C# - EF 6 - FK Relationship (Invoice Class)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm designing an invoice class. To put it simple:

- I'm using EF 6 code-first with Fluent-API.
- The tables(classes): Invoice, Supplier, Customer, Store

The invoice class has an issuer and an addressee.
I want something like 'IssuerId' and 'AddresseeId'

The issuer could be either the supplier (for buying items) or the store (for selling/returning items) and the addressee could be either the supplier (for returning items), the customer (for selling items) or the store (for buying items).

Of course I don't want to create FK columns for each one of 'em, because only two would be used for each invoice and the others would be null.

The problem as explained: The addressee and the issuer could be any of those tables for each invoice.

I thought adding an enum as a discriminator to tell EF which table my FK is pointing to:

```
public int AdresseeId { get; set; }
public AdresseeType AdresseeType { get; set; } // 'C' is customer, 'S' is supplier...
```

But I need the relationships to work and navigation properties too. I'm trying to find the most clean solution for this case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See [here][1] for an excellent description of your problem and possible solutions


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/441111/4684493

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Table Per Concrete Type inheritance mapping strategy. Create an abstract class `Addressee` that contains all the properties common to any addressee and then let your `Customer`, `Supplier`, and `Store` entities inherit from it. The collection property on your `Invoice` will be of type `Addressee`. In your entity mapping configuration, use the `MapInheritedProperties()` option.

This article will give you more information and examples.
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: There is a problem there: supplier and store can be either addressee or issuer, and it's not possible to do multi-inheritance.

Comment: I think (though I'm not certain) it should work with an interface `IAddressee` instead of an abstract class, in which case you could implement `IIssuer` as well. Just know that table-per-concrete-type has some caveats regarding identity columns that  you have to address.