# Joining pivot table vs. duplicating columns

Tags: database, orm, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm making a game, where players make moves one by one. I have following tables:

```
╔═════════╗
║ players ║
╠═════════╣
║ id      ║
║ name    ║
╚═════════╝
╔════════════╗
║   games    ║
╠════════════╣
║ id         ║
║ started_at ║
╚════════════╝
╔═════════════╗
║ game_player ║
╠═════════════╣
║ id          ║
║ game_id     ║
║ player_id   ║
║ turn        ║
╚═════════════╝
```

Now, I'd like to add `moves` table to keep track of game's history. I'm not sure which way is better:

1) Connect `moves` with pivot table `game_player` like this:

```
╔════════════════╗
║     moves      ║
╠════════════════╣
║ id             ║
║ game_player_id ║
║ made_at        ║
╚════════════════╝
```

2) Duplicate `game_id` and `player_id` pair like this:

```
╔═══════════╗
║   moves   ║
╠═══════════╣
║ id        ║
║ game_id   ║
║ player_id ║
║ made_at   ║
╚═══════════╝
```

The first solution makes my data more concise, there is no way to put unexisting game-player pair if I use foreign keys.

The second solution is easier to handle with ORM.

How should this problem be solved? Is there any way to use first idea comfortably with ORM, perhaps by creating another entity for game-player pairs, like `Participation`? How would you guys do it?

Comment: There is not much Relational integrity in either scheme.  Please confirm: It is a two-player (not multiple-player) game, and the moves alternate between the players.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA This is multiplayer game, 1 player up to 4, but I wouldn't like to limit it to 4, because I might have new idea in the future.

Comment: Please review the Answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Initial Response

Your files do not have uniqueness or integrity.  As I understand it, you want a Relational database, with Relational integrity, power, and speed.

Here is a Data Model, as a discussion point.  Obviously it is not complete, as many details need to be raised and closed.  However, getting somthing out there for you is faster than a question-and-answer back-and-forth, using this SO media.

Fist Draft [**Game Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Robo%20Robok%20DM.pdf)

Please comment/discuss.

If you are not used to the Notation, please be advised that every little tick, notch, and mark, the solid vs dashed lines, the square vs round corners, means something very specific.  Refer to the [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf).

### Response to Comments

> *It seems to be far too complicated for the goal*

Which goal ?

If your goal is a Relational Database (as part of whatever other goals you have for the project), then that is the minimum "complexity", the configuration that is  required to produce a Relational Database, with Relational Integrity.  So the onus is on you to climb that learning curve.

Otherwise, please remove the `database` and `relational-database` tags from your question.

> *How is my first idea against database integrity?*

It isn't *against* integrity, it is **absent** integrity, the kind that is normal, ordinary, expected, in a Relational Database.  Clearly, you have been reading books that allege to be about "relational databases", written by people who are evidently clueless about Relational Databases, and you have implemented what they advise, or what you have seen others do.

- You have no **row uniqueness** as demanded by the *Relational Model*.  Eg. duplicate Player.names are allowed.  Eg there is no context for a game.
- You have `ID` fields in every file. That gives Record ID (in an RFS) uniqueness, but **no row uniqueness**.  Please read [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726132/484814) carefully.
- Eg. In both your (1) and (2), you allow moves by players that are not constrained to the game that they are playing.  Any existing player_id and game_id is allowed.

The above is just an example of the *type* of integrity errors you have, I have not listed them all.

My suggested model fixes all the integrity errors, I did not enumerate all the errors that I fixed, I just gave you a valid database.

> *getting somthing out there for you is faster than a question-and-answer back-and-forth*

Eg:

- The notion of a game that exists independently is not reasonable.  A game only exists in the context of a player who started one.  So I have implemented that.  That improves the *Identifiers* and game is now more contextual.
- Likewise, the notion of a move that exist without a game, or without players who are playing in that specific game, is not reasonable.  Yo have that.  The model fixes that.
- First I have responders who join the game, that one player started.  The sum of them are the players for that specific game.
- Next, I have moves that are constrained to each specific game.
- Next, I have moves that are constrained to each specific palyer in each specific game.
- Next, in order to implement that correctly, I use a basic, Relational, **Basetype::Subtype** structure.  This differentiates the initiating_player and the responding_players.  It also allows me to apply the relevant constraints to the correct tables.  The `is_initiator` column Discriminates the Basetype.

  - If you would like more information on Subtypes, please study [**this document**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf).
- All but one `ID` columns have disappeared, naturally, without trying to get rid of them.  The one remaining for player_id is valid only because player.name might be too wide.  If player.name is *not* their real name, if it is an user_name (eg. `CHAR(12))`, then change player_id to user_name, and the whole structure will be better.  Please advise, and I will improve the model.

Now we have the basis for a Relational Database.  I did label it a first draft, I expected questions and perhaps minor changes. I did not expect to cover the large gap between Record Filing Systems and Relational Databases.  Feel free to ask questions, I might suggest opening a new question for those that require a detailed answer.

Comment: It seems to be far too complicated for the goal.

Comment: @Robo Robok. I responded in the Answer.

Comment: How is my first idea against database integrity?

Comment: @Robo Robok. I responded in the Answer.

Comment: You are wrong with `In both your (1) and (2), you allow moves by players that are not constrained to the game that they are playing`. In my first idea, I don't allow any game/user pair, only those who are actually playing. And as for the row uniqueness, I don't see how is it related to the topic. How do you know whether my names are unique indexes or not? They actually are, but it doesn't matter for my question.