# Can a column of a table refer to two or more tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a doubt regarding the construction of a database ( sql ) . I'm simulating the database of a bank , and the transaction table have an attribute type transaction , how do I indicate that this attribute can be either withdrawal , deposit or bank ? which are other tables in my database .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with constraints. But you can do something like this: set two fields in the `transactions` table (`transaction_type` and `transaction_id`) and then you can use numbers (or strings) to refer to each table. For example: `transaction_type` 1 can refers to `deposits` table. Then, in your code, you can search for the record with `id = transactions.transaction_id` on the `deposits` table.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables#answer-441111) answer.