# Use 1 junction table with 3 foreign keys Or 2 junction tables with shared sequencing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, junction-table

I have 3 tables that I am trying to *properly* create relationships between:

- game phase
- game event (a step in a 'game phase')
- action window (a radically different kind of step in a 'game phase')

A 'game phase' can have one or more 'game event(s)', and a 'game event' can happen in one or more 'game phase(s)'. (Many-to-many)

A 'game phase' can have one or more 'action window(s)', and an 'action window' can happen in one or more 'game phase(s)'. (Many-to-many)

A 'game event' is not related to an 'action window'.

**However**, I hesitate to create 2 separate junction tables because both 'game events' and 'action windows' share the same *order of occurrence* (aka sequence) numbering system per 'game phase'. I'm not sure how I would maintain that.

What is the most proper way to lay out these tables while still being able to easily track the order of occurence?

Comment: So "game events" and "action windows" *are* related by order of occurrence?  My gut suggests going with a single intersection table having sequence number as the primary key. Can you post some (partial) table definitions?

Comment: The sequence number will have to be editable. Games have rule changes so I wouldn't want to set it in stone by making it the primary key. It would work as another column. I am still hesitant to make any junction table with 3+ foreign keys. It'd have to have a constraint that only allows either "game events" id or "action windows" to be filled out.

Comment: For any given `game phase`, is the number of `events` and `actions` always the same? In other words, is it possible, that some phase has 5 events and 6 actions?  If yes, what will be the sequence numbers for them? If yes, I'd create two separate junction tables, if no, I'd create one junction table.

Comment: Game event and action window both being steps, are these two tables very different from each other or quite similar? Could you show us your table definitions?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes it is possible for one phase to have 5 events & 6 actions. The sequence numbers would be 1 through 11 in any order needed.

Comment: @Glyph, so you need 11 rows somewhere to store sequence numbers from 1 through 11. It may make sense to have an extra separate table for sequence numbers after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a design that represents ***sequences*** of *'game events'* and *'action windows'*, related each other by belonging to a same sequence in the same sequence step.

That is to say, introducing "*gaming sequence*" and "*gaming sequence detail*" entities, the junction table is avoided "by design", representing the shared sequencing fact of '*game event(s)*' and '*action window(s)*' by mean of having the same *sequence step* in a "*gaming sequence*" (avoidance due to the consideration that "*A 'game event' is not related to an 'action window'*").

### SCHEMA

```
+--------------+ 1      1,n +-------------------+ 1,n
|  game_phase  +------------+  game_phase_play  +----+
|              |            |                   |    |
+--------------+            +-------------------+    |
                                                     |
                                                     | 1
+--------------------------+ 1,n         1 +---------+---------+
|  gaming_sequence_detail  +---------------+  gaming_sequence  |
|                          |               |                   |
++--------+----------------+               +-----+-------------+
 | 1,n    |                                      |
 |        +---+  seq_step                        +---+ seq_steps_number
 |
 |
 |                                      +--------------+
 |                                +-----+  game_event  |
 | 1,n +----------------+         |     |              |
 +-----+  gaming_value  | <-------+     +--------------+
       |                |         |     +-----------------+
       +----------------+         +-----+  action_window  |
                                        |                 |
                                        +-----------------+
```

### PREFIXES

```
gph_                    === game_phase_
gseq_                   === gaming_sequence_
gv_                     === gaming_value_
```

### TABLES

```
game_phase              ( id , description, ... )
game_phase_play         ( id , gph_id, gseq_id, date, description, ... )
gaming_sequence         ( id, seq_steps_number, ... )
gaming_value            ( id , type, ... )
gaming_sequence_detail  ( gseq_id, gv_id, seq_step, ... )
```

I've also introduced a generalization entity for '*game event(s)*' and '*action window(s)*' named "*gaming value*", useful for being contained in a "*gaming sequence*". This generalization could represent a kind of gaming immutable value (of 2 different types in our case, but extensible) and so the chosen naming (had been switching from "*gaming objectified*" and "*gaming observable*").

'*gaming value(s)*' of the two types are "*stepped together*" in the *gaming sequence* by means of equality of the `(gseq_id, seq_step)` pair in `gaming_sequence_detail` (one could argue that this kind of "*pairing*" is a relationship; this kind of solution acts more like representing *sibilings* in a sequence step, permitting also to extend to more than 2 types of '*gaming values*').

'*game event(s)*' and '*action window(s)*' in a *gaming sequence detail* could be independently modified and also could appear "*unpaired*".

A constraint in `gaming_sequence_detail` is that for every `seq_step` value could exist one `game_event` and one `action_window` and so the maximum cardinality of `seq_step` for a single `gseq_id` is 2.

If it's the case, the same `gaming_value` could also appear more than once in the same sequence. Moreover this design could also represent shared sequences between different *'game phase play(s)'*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you explain what gaming_observable is?

Comment: Hy @Glyph. I have got difficulties for naming this entity, due maybe to my poor english. Anyway i switched from "gaming objectified" but could more  appropriately be named "gaming value". It's some kind of gaming value type isolated in different immutable values.

Comment: I've updated with new naming and explanation. Thanks for the voting :)

Answer (score 2):

Make one table junction like:

## game_phase_steps

```
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
| id | phase_id  | rank  |   type   | step_id |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |    1  | event    |       2 |
|  2 |         1 |    2  | action   |       1 |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+
```

- id - primary key for game_phase_steps
- phase_id - foreign key for game phase
- rank - unique order of occurrence of step in game phase
- type - game phase can have event or action
- step_id - event_id for foreign reference of game event or action_id for foreign reference of action window

Don't know how your `game_event` and `action_window` are structured.
But if you need all data in single query, them you probably need to perform two left joins, one onto `game_event` and one onto `action_window`, and return the fields you want from the appropriate join table something like this:

```
game_phase_steps g
LEFT JOIN game_event e
    ON game_phase_steps.type = "event" 
        AND game_phase_steps.step_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN action_window a
    ON game_phase_steps.type = "action" 
        AND game_phase_steps.step_id = a.id
```

and if your tables are structured differently then you might need select statement like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN g.type = "event" THEN e.some_field ELSE a.some_field END
```

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer. Is it possible for one foreign-key column (step_id in your example) to point to 2 primary keys like that? I'm using PostgreSQL. This might be something I can google but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: You don't need to tie foreign key by structure. You can tie that logically. Id type is `event` then step_id would be primary key of game_event table. You can see [this reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables) If you want to make tight structure. Then you can make 2 different tables for references with foreign keys. And make one more table referencing those 2 tables for order (i.e. rank).