# How to make multiple foreignkey value in 1 column?

Tags: mysql

how to make the output like this? From 4 tables (rate, cost, tools, car)

```
|`RateID` | `Costing` | `Toolsfk` and `CarFK` |
|---------------------------------------------|
|    1    |    1000   |     1004              |
|    2    |    2000   |     2003              |
```

this is the tables

[image]

i want to 2 or more Foreignkey in 1 column, should I use `CONCAT`? but, as I know, `CONCAT` is for output only. So, what if for output and input data in database? just use `Insert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

polymorphic association is not possible, polymorphic association means single column has more than one foreign key for different tables. foreign key can target only one table at a time, a single column foreign key can't refer more than one tables, if u want to refer more than one table using single column then there are two ways..

1- creating identical table of referenced table 
2- use two columns in a table, one column refer tools table and one column refer car table

below is a link from where you can take refrence

([Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables))

Comment: ohh, i get it. just make another table and that's 1 table refrence 2 other table. okay, thanks