# TypeORM Entity Inheritance OneToMany relation

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have `NoShow` abstract class which is parent for `ActiveNoShow` and `InactiveNoShow`.
And `NoShow` have OneToMany relationship with `NoShowPhoto`.

So NoShowPhoto is like the below:

```
@Entity()
export class NoShowPhoto extends Photo {
  @ManyToOne(() => NoShow, (noShow) => noShow.photos)
  noShow: NoShow;
}
```

In this case, NoShow table is created and NoShowPhoto's relationship is set with `NoShow`.

InactiveNoShow.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class InactiveNoShow extends NoShow {
    
    @Column()
    reason: 0 | 1;
}
```

ActiveNoShow.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class ActiveNoShow extends NoShow {
  // nothing 
}
```

But what I want to create is `ActiveNoshow` and `InactiveNoShow`, not just `NoShow`.
And the relation should be set

1. between `ActiveNoShow` and `NoShowPhoto`
2. between `InactiveNosHow` and `NoShowPhoto`.

You can see as ERD below:
[image]

The red lines is what I would like to set relation and don't want to create `NoShow` table.

Is there anyway to inherit OneToMany relation to `ActiveNoShow` and `InactiveNoShow`?

**self-answer:**

A column cannot be the foreign key for two tables at once.

[Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables)

Comment: I request you to share the entity-relationship diagram - that would be helpful to understand the queston

Comment: Thank you for comment. I added with more codes.

Comment: A column cannot be the foreign key for two tables at once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables