# How to create a composite foreign key from fields in different tables?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I currently populate a personal tennis statistics database by pulling SQL statements from an API and then running them. The statements from the API assume that there are 6 tables:

- Male players
- Female players
- Male tournaments
- Female tournaments
- Male matches
- Female matches

Note: There is no unique primary key for the match tables - they use a composite primary key consisting of player ids, tournament ids and a round id.

As the male and female versions of the tables are identical I'm trying to import the data into single tables for players, tournaments and matches. I can also utilise an auto-generated primary key for further operations and a `tour_id` field to distinguish between male and female when loading new data.

For the combined `match` table I'd like to use the combination of the original API ids for players and tournaments along with the `tour_id` as composite foreign keys. This means I can easily execute the API statement as I'll know what the original id is and whether it is male or female. To that end I've got as far as building by table classes as follows:

```
class Player(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tournament"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "test"})

    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orig_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    tour_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    match = relationship(
        "Match",
        primaryjoin=(
            f"or_(and_(Player.orig_id == Match.player_orig_id_p1, Player.tour_id == Tournament.tour_id), "
            f"and_(Player.orig_id == Match.player_orig_id_p2, Player.tour_id == Tournament.tour_id))"
        ),
        overlaps="fk_p1, fk_p2",
    )


class Match(Base):

    __tablename__ = "match"
    __table_args__ = (
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["tournament_orig_id", "tournament.tour_id"],
            ["tournament.orig_id", "tournament.tour_id"],
            "fk_tournament",
        ),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["player_orig_id_p1", "tournament.tour_id"],
            ["player.orig_id", "player.tour_id"],
            "fk_p1",
        ),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["player_orig_id_p2", "tournament.tour_id"],
            ["player.orig_id", "player.tour_id"],
            "fk_p2",
        ),
        {"schema": "test"},
    )

    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tournament_orig_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    round_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    player_orig_id_p1 = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    player_orig_id_p2 = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    tournament = relationship("Tournament", back_populates="match")


class Tournament(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tournament"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "test"})

    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orig_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    tour_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    match = relationship("Match", back_populates="tournament")
```

The error I'm currently running into is:

```
Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table 'match': no column named 'tournament.tour_id' is present.
```

This is perfectly understandable as the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html?highlight=foreignkeyconstraint#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint.params.columns) are clear:

> **columns** – A sequence of local column names.

I'm clearly trying to refer to the `tour_id` field in the `tournament` table which SA doesn't like. However, I can't figure out a way to create the composite foreign key without adding a `tour_id` field to the `match` table which wouldn't be in line with a normalised table structure.

Any ideas on possible ways forward?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/441001/14853083

Comment: don't create separate identical tables; it will just make things harder. here, there should not be separate tables for male vs female

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - thanks for the link. I'm not too sure how this relates to my question though? I'm not looking to have an FK point at two tables - I'm trying to create a composite FK to link to a single table. Was there a particular answer you thought was relevant?

Comment: @ysth - I definitely don't want to create identical tables!!

Comment: @Jossy Your title refers to _"composite foreign key from fields in different tables"_. The only way I can interpret that is that you want one FK to point at two different tables, and one of the answers specifically says you can't do that. Your comment above says that's **not** what you want, so now I have no idea what you do want.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - as per my comment I'm trying to create a composite FK to link to a single table. I think you may be coming at this from a MySQL perspective when I was thinking of this as more of an SQLAlchemy syntax question...